# Adding value to variable not working just appending on

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to take the `quantity` then add in the `order` number to it then resave the value of `quantity`.

```
// update expendable quantity POST
  app.post('/dashboard/it/expendable/:id',
    setRedirect({auth: '/login', success: '/dashboard/it/expendable', failure: '/dashboard/it/expendable'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {
      Expendable.findById(req.parms.id, function(err, expendable) {
        if (err) return (err);
        expendable.quantity = expendable.quantity + req.body.order;
        expendable.save(function(err) {
          if (err) return (err);
            req.flash('success', { msg: 'Expendable checked out.' });
            res.redirect(req.redirect.success);
        });
      });
      next();
    });
```

It currently just adds the `req.body.order` onto the end of the `expendable.quantity` instead of adding it to it numerically.

I don't see why it is not working, I have similar code using `-` and it works but but `+` doesn't. I did look on google to see and everything I found showed just to use `var1 + var2`.

I did check datatype and it is number and the input is a number type as well.

Comment: I would parse them into numbers, it's most likely that one of them is a string and in that case, it appends: "5" + 5 = "55"

Comment: @StephenMiller is there a way I can check using mongo to see the datatypes of each part of the user account.

Comment: I have not used mongo but generally, it should be the type you marked it as in the database, you could check the type yourself. If you don't already I would look into using lodash, an awesome utility lib designed for tasks like this. `_.isString(num) == boolean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would parse them into numbers, it's most likely that one of them is a string and in that case, it appends: `"5" + 5 = "55"`,  `"5" - 5 = 0`

[image: example of adding and minus with a string]

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I used native JS and did it with `var foo = Number(bar);`

Comment: Awesome! if it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer, thank you!